# Как добавить свой поиск в контекстное меню google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, браузер, google-customsearch-api

хотелось бы добавить свой поиск в контекстное меню браузера google chrome, поисковую службу я уже создал, теперь хотелось бы её добавить в контекстное меню, знает ли кто-нибудь как это сделать ?
На рисунке ниже показано то самое контекстное меню (когда выделяешь текст и нажимаешь правую клавишу мыши)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]